# Where can i find the source code of predefined class and function

Tags: ros, matlab, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i want to know where can i find the source code of predefined class and function.
for exemple:
Class : ExampleHelperGazeboCommunicator()
Function:exampleHelperROSPoseCallback
Function:exampleHelperGazeboAvoidanceTimer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215721/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-predefined-class-and-function/) by [hamdicharef](https://answers.ros.org/users/23546/hamdicharef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed it using apt-get you probably don't have the source code and just grabbed the pre-compiled binaries.
Best thing is to go to [gazebo's repository](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo) and clone it to your computer then do a text search for those functions. I think the search function you would need would be

```
grep -rnw yourFunctionHere
```

on the root folder of the repository. Believe it or not BitBucket doesn't offer a search function yet !!!

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0